# why is there a need to echo "recaptcha_get_html"?

Tags: php, html, css, recaptcha

all. I've been trying to integrate Google's reCAPTCHA, and seem to be failing when trying to echo recaptcha_get_html. It comes up with an undefined function error. I've looked everywhere and can't seem to get a straight answer. I'm semi-good with PHP, and don't fully understand everything. Can someone please explain how I can find the missing function. So my question is, is there a need to echo this function?. Here's my code:

```
  <form class="" action="verify.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="email" value=" enter email address" onFocus="if(this.value==' enter email address')this.value='';" style="height:18px; width:218px; color: #cccccc; border: 1 solid #000000; background-color: #5e5e5e; font: xx-small Verdana">
      &nbsp; <br><br>
      <?php
        require_once('recaptchalib.php');
        $publickey = "// Public Key";
        echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
      ?>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" id="sendform" name='send' value="   send   " style="cursor: hand; height:18px; border: 1 solid #000000; background-color:#5e5e5e; color: #cccccc; font: xx-small Verdana; font-weight:bold">
    </form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Last time I checked the client-side was entirely based on JavaScript: https://github.com/google/recaptcha/blob/master/examples/example-captcha.php

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all, no you do not need to echo that function!
As J-H meantioned, you might first want to update to the lastest version of recaptcha.
Here is how I implemented google recaptcha in php

```
$secret = "Your secret key";
$reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);
    if ($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) {
        $response = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse ( 
   $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]);
    }

    if(!($response != null && $response->success)) ...
      //it was successfully
```

Notice how I do not echo anything. Also, the public key should be in the html, the private key should be in the PHP. The public key should not be in the PHP, I do not know if that was a typo but that could also be another problem. Finally, it looks as though you are not using the html correctly for the google recaptcha api, atleast the new one.
Include `<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>`
in your header and `<div style="margin:10px auto 0 auto; width:330px" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="YOUR_SITE_KEY"></div>`
where you want the recaptcha to appear. Then you will have it all working. Cheers

Comment: The client side works fine, it's just the verification that I don't get, because clients are saying that they are still getting spam come through.

Comment: And verify.php doesn't seem to be providing any feedback.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you are working with the Version 1.0 which is no longer supported:
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/php

Comment: More of a comment than an answer dont you think?